# How to configure Gitlab CI for being run on every branch push?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My builds are being correctly run and with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, but just for `master` branch. If I checkout a new branch, then make changes on it, commit and push, the builds are not being triggered (still having the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, of course).

As `master` is my production branch, I want to run my builds on development and features branches, to be sure that the tests and the code style checkings are properly passed.

How do I configure Gitlab for making builds for every branch?

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - /usr/bin/env composer install

php_syntax_check:
  stage: test
  script:
    - vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2 src
```

- Gitlab version: **GitLab Community Edition 8.14.4**
- gitlab-ci-multi-runner version: **1.8.1**

Comment: Can we have a look at your current .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Comment: Hello @Jawad, I've edited the first post with the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Comment: Interesting... This should run the build regardless of the branch you're using since there are no "except", "only" or "when" filters. What version of gitlab and gitlab-ci-multi-runner are you using? Also, are you sure the .gitlab-ci.yml file is also on those branches you're trying to build?

Comment: @Jawad I've added the versions of both Gitlab and the runner. The file exists in other branches; I created them from `master`, after checking that for this branch the runner was working.

Comment: What happens if you go to your gitlab and into pipelines then click "run pipeline" and run the pipeline for one of those branches instead of master?
Anyway, I don't see anything wrong with your configuration so outside of a regression from gitlab or gitlab-ci-multi-runner introduced in the latest versions which you are using, I don't see what's wrong... I would suggest opening an issue on either of the following  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues or https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues and maybe mention this discussion.